# Delphi Form Height Width Changing in .DFM file on different developer machines

Tags: forms, delphi, height, width

We have two different developer machines using the same .pas file
any time one developer changes something on the a form the form.width in the .dfm file can change
on one machine the Form (width = 651) and (ClientWidth = 635)
the other machine the Form (width = 643) and (ClientWidth = 635)

I would like to know why the (Width and Height) are changing in the forms .dfm file

I want to see at run time a breakdown of the Calculations + reasons of the difference between 
(ClientHeight and Height) and (ClientWidth and Width)

so if (width = 651) and (ClientWidth = 635)
How can i at run time check the windows border width or whatever i need to workout the difference between these values?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want to see what is the actual values for the difference between width and clientwidth. e.g. border size etc

Comment: That's all? Aren't you already doing that math? `WidthDiff := Width - ClientWidth; HeightDiff := Height - ClientHeight;` Or were you also looking to calculate the Window Title area's non-client height?

Comment: the problem is that on two different machines the border size could be different so i want to see that on machine 1 the border width is 8 and on machine 2 the border width is 7 so i can see why there is a difference between the width on two different machines

Comment: Is the above math not sufficient? All you need to do is divide that by two. Again, do you need to know the non-client area dimensions? Because that's another topic which you should say. As it stands, your question is asking for an extremely basic math problem. I suggest removing anything from your question regarding "calculating difference", and instead ask about the non-client region of a form.

Comment: Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The math above doesn't work for height because its not just borders

Comment: That's precisely what I mean by "Non-Client Area". It's a bit different from calculating border size of width/height clientwidth/clientheight differences.

Answer (score 1):

The Reason the .DFM file was changing was because there were some differences in the windows Registry settings between two machines
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
which was causing the border, title, form caption heights/widths to be different

If you run the below functions using the same exe you can potentially get different results

**Height calculation**
//This gets the Form Caption Height
GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION )
//This gets the Form Border width
GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME) 
//This get the Forms mainMenu Height
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU)

here is an example function to show the breakup of the Height Calculation

```
function CalcHeightDifference : String;
  var iActualHeightDifference : integer;
      iCalcHeightDifference : integer;
      sInfo : String;
begin
  iCalcHeightDifference := 0;
  iActualHeightDifference := self.Height - Self.ClientHeight;

  //Caption
  iCalcHeightDifference := iCalcHeightDifference + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION );
  sInfo := ' + Form Caption = ' + inttostr( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION ) );

  //Borders
  iCalcHeightDifference := iCalcHeightDifference + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME);
  sInfo := sInfo + sLineBreak + ' + Border Height(' + inttostr( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME)) + ') times two = ' + inttostr( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME)+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME)  );

  //Menu
  if self.Menu <> nil then begin
    iCalcHeightDifference := iCalcHeightDifference + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU);
    sInfo := sInfo + sLineBreak + ' + Form MainMenu = ' + inttostr( GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU) );
  end;

  result := format( 'Form.ClientHeight=%d', [Self.ClientHeight])
          + sLineBreak
          + format('Form.Height=%d', [Self.Height])
          + sLineBreak
          + format('The Height Difference of %d is made up of', [Self.Height-Self.ClientHeight])
          + sLineBreak
          + sInfo
          + sLineBreak
          + format(' Total( %d )', [iCalcHeightDifference])     ;
end;
```

**Width Calculation**
//This gets the Form Border width
GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME)

here is an example function to show the breakup of the Width calculation

```
function CalcWidthDifference : String;
  var iActualWidthDifference : integer;
    iCalcWidthDifference : integer;
    sInfo : String;
begin
  iCalcWidthDifference := 0;
  iActualWidthDifference := self.Width - Self.ClientWidth;

  //Borders
  iCalcWidthDifference := GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME);
  sInfo := ' + Border Width(' + inttostr( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME) ) + ') times Two = ' + inttostr( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME)+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME) );

  result := format( 'Form.ClientWidth=%d', [Self.ClientWidth])
          + sLineBreak
          + format('Form.Width=%d', [Self.Width])
          + sLineBreak
          + format('The Width Difference of %d is made up of', [Self.Width-Self.ClientWidth])
          + sLineBreak
          + sInfo
          + sLineBreak
          + format(' Total( %d )', [iCalcWidthDifference])    ;
end;
```

All this because we had two windows development machines that were randomly changing the .DFM files width on forms - and panels etc 
i've included some screen shots below ran from the same exe on different machines to show that the width is different. and if i was to change something on that form at design time the .dfm file will be saving with different widths

Machine 1[image: Machine 1]
Machine 2[image: Machine 2]

Comment: This is the answer?

Comment: I've edited the answer does it make more sense now? i can remove the question if it is not going to be of use to anyone, just thought it might help someone else who comes across the same issue